# How to determine if a status bar will show on the page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to use the statusbar SP api from here

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/28/status-bar-in-sharepoint-2013/

in my SP2013 environment. I can use the add status function to put a new status on the yellow status bar. But if the page had no other status bar to begin with, then it just puts the text and doesn't display the yellow bar. It's like I need to somehow check if the yellow bar was going to show or not.

Does anyone know how to check this without using timeouts?

Thanks

Comment: nevermind, it seems, you need to manually call `SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(id, "red");` or whatever color you want in addition.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/venkatx5/archive/2010/11/18/how-to-use-status-bar-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx